# Use g-brief address field layout to produce labels

Tags: templates, addresses

I have a number of letters created with the document class [`g-brief`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/g-brief) and would like to generate labels (does not have to be automatic; cut-and-paste would be ok for now) from the address used in each letter. I have had some minor success in using the [`labels`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/labels) package, but the labels do not look as good as the `g-brief` label, mostly I miss the sender above the recipient.

Any ideas how to "merge" these two packages? I. e. have the same "look" of the address field, just printed on labels?

Also, has anyone had any success in using the `\skiplabels`option of the  `labels`package? If I use the option all labels are placed all over the page... That's why I use the double tilde in my code.

`labels` code I use so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{labels}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
%\LabelInfotrue
%\LabelGridtrue
\TopBorder=5mm
\BottomBorder=5mm
\LeftBorder=20mm
\RightBorder=2mm
\LabelRows=6
\LabelCols=2
%\numberoflabels=24
\begin{document}

\begin{labels}
~
~

{\tiny Christian Schmidt - My Address 123 - 31415 My City}
Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG
\emph{Herrn Peter Mustermann}
Musterstrasse 12a
\hspace{1mm}
\textbf{12345 Musterhausen}
\end{labels}
\end{document}
```

Edit: The solution for Staples type 2x6 / 105mm x 48mm labels:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}

\usepackage[]{ticket}
\usepackage[margin=2mm]{geometry}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\ticketNumbers{2}{6}
\ticketSize{104}{44}
\ticketDistance{0}{4}

\newif\iftrennlinien

\renewcommand*{\ticketdefault}{\small
      \put(0,39){\makebox(85,4)
      {\scriptsize \textrm{\retouradresse}}}
      \iftrennlinien \put(0, 38.9){\line(1,0){85}} \fi
}
\newcommand*{\myticket}[2][]{\ticket{\small
      \put(0,39){\makebox(85,4)
      {\scriptsize \textrm{\retouradresse}}}
      \put(8,32.85){\parbox[t]{3in}{\textbf{#1} \par \vspace{2mm} #2}}
}}

\newcommand*{\retouradresse}{My Name $\cdot$ My Street 123 $\cdot$ 31415 My City}

\begin{document}
\trennlinientrue
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket[E I N S C H R E I B E N]{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket[R E C H N U N G]{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know, [`g-brief`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/g-brief) is not part of the [KOMA-Script bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), which offers its own document class for letters called `scrlttr2`. So which one are you actually using, `\documentclass{g-brief}`/`\documentclass{g-brief2}` or `\documentclass{scrlttr2}`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; but I actually do use ``g-brief``.

Comment: You should update your example, then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a solution using the [`ticket`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ticket) package - in my opinion, it is more flexible and easier to use than the [`labels`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/labels) package (e. g. you can specify the with and height of the labels directly). It reproduces the address layout of [`g-brief(2)`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/g-brief) exactly and should be easy to modify according to your needs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}

\usepackage[crossmark]{ticket}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\ticketNumbers{2}{6}
\ticketSize{85}{42.85}
\ticketDistance{0}{0}

\newif\iftrennlinien

\renewcommand*{\ticketdefault}{\small
      \put(0,39){\makebox(85,4)
      {\scriptsize \textrm{\retouradresse}}}
      \iftrennlinien \put(0, 38.9){\line(1,0){85}} \fi
}
\newcommand*{\myticket}[2][]{\ticket{\small
      \put(0,39){\makebox(85,4)
      {\scriptsize \textrm{\retouradresse}}}
      \put(8,32.85){\parbox[t]{3in}{\textbf{#1} \par \vspace{2mm} #2}}
}}

\newcommand*{\retouradresse}{Christian Schmidt $\cdot$ My Address 123 $\cdot$ 31415 My City}

\begin{document}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket[E I N S C H R E I B E N]{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket[R E C H N U N G]{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\trennlinientrue
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\myticket{Testfirma GmbH \& Co. KG\\Herrn Peter Mustermann\\Musterstrasse 12a\\12345 Musterhausen}
\end{document}
```

Use this template as follows: The `\retouradresse` macro contains the the return address printed on top of every label. The recipient is added separately for each label using the custom `\myticket` command which expects the address as a mandatory argument. Furthermore, you can have an optional argument to add something like "Invoice" in bold letters above the address. If you want a line under the return address, use `\trennlinientrue`.

(I used the exact macro names and the code from `g-brief`, so everything should be pretty familiar.)

This is how the labels look like:
[image: labels produced by the above code]

Comment: Perfect - Thank you! It has all the customizations I could never had hoped for ;)