# Generating labels for envelopes

Tags: letters, envlab

I have a list of 50 addresses for letters I have to send, and in LaTeX I am trying to create labels to stick on envelopes. I have a clear A4 sheet for printing (e.g. 10x2 fields) something similar as in the figure below, so I also have to take care of the geometry.

[image: Example of address label paper]

I don't need to generate bar codes like for the US Postal Service, and similar standards... I had seen the envlab package but it doesn't seem to fulfil my needs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does an answer here help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49630/use-g-brief-address-field-layout-to-produce-labels

Comment: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the following may not be the best, but why not:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage,tikz}
\usepackage{framed,multicol}

% This command just serves for the single repeated label. Of course these will not 
% be the same but will yield the result.
\newcommand{\repeatedlabel}[1]{%
\foreach \x in {1,...,#1}%
{%
\addresslabel
}%
}

% Sample address 
\def\addresslabel{%
\begin{framed}
Janine Lee\par
641 Caslon Place\par
Hollywood, CA 9015B
\end{framed}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\repeatedlabel{8}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```